# How to inject jQuery to a plugin within a ESM

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-modules

My code is failing because a plugin is expecting a jQuery object, but I'm not sure how to pass it in.

I'm using modules (and importmap), but the [javascript plugin](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle/blob/master/Resources/public/js/select2entity.js) isn't a module.

In webpack, i set autoProvideJQuery to trun and I could do a require().  Now I'm not sure what to do.

My hackish attempts.  Set up an importmap for jquery and the plugin, then

```
    <script type="module">
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    window.jQuery = jQuery;

    import '@tetranz/select2entity-bundle'

</script>
```

I keep getting an undefined reference jQuery.  Not too surprising, but I can't figure out how to "inject" jQuery into the plugin.